# macbook pro 7,1 won't shut down without holding power button - 12.10

Tags: 12.10, freeze, shutdown, macbook

Using the 64 bit desktop version of Ubuntu 12.10, macbook pro 7,1 won't shutdown or reboot, it will only go to a blank screen and then hang there forever until the power button is held down for 3 seconds.

Comment: The documentation for Lucid offers this advice:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Lucid#Reboot
which, unfortunately, changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the driver for the nvidia graphics card was causing this, however I don't know why. I was using the nvidia-current driver, as the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal#Activate_proprietary_nvidia_driver) told me to do.

**The solution:** change the driver the graphics card is using.
*Software Sources > Additional Drivers >* and change the nvidia driver to nvidia-experimental-304

Conclusively:

**Unable to reboot/shutdown:**

- nvidia-current
- nvidia-current-updates
- nvidia-experimental-310

**Able to reboot/shutdown:**

- nvidia-experimental-304
- nouveau(but with other graphical problems)

Comment: If anyone has any additional information, please post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2127691&p=12566794#post12566794) or let me know somehow.